# Consider a cell as an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some data with which i have to create a pdf. In one cell of the raw data, there is a list of weights such as 12.34kg,15.62kg,34.34kg for example. When I write them into an other sheet in order to generate my pdf, i want to write every weight into a different cell, one under the other such as : 12.34kg in cell C2 15.62kg in cell C3 and 34.34kg in cell C4.

I'm struggling with this task... There is how i'm trying to perform but doesn't work, there is an issue with the setValues method...

```
function mySplit() { 
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var cell = String(doc.getRange("J21").getValues()); 
  var array =[{}]; 
  array = cell.split(","); 
  for (var j = 0; j<= array1.length; j++)
  { 
    doc.getRange(21+j,10,1,1).setValues(array[0][j]);  
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues:**

- In your code, you use `getValues()` to get the value of a single
  element.  In this particular scenario, you should use `getValue()`
  instead.
- You don't need to predefine `array` and in your code `array1` hasn't been defined anywhere.
- `String()` is also redundant and wrong, the cell value will be string in this case by default.

---

**Solution:**

Given that `12.34kg,15.62kg,34.34kg` is on cell **J21**, the following script will populate `12.34kg`,`15.62kg` and `34.34kg` in cells **J21**,**J22** and **J23** respectively:

```
function mySplit() { 
  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var cell = doc.getRange("J21").getValue();
  var array = cell.split(","); 
  
  for (var j = 0; j<= array.length; j++)
  {
    doc.getRange(21+j,10).setValue(array[j]);  
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there is already an answer that solves your issue, setting the value of each different cell individually via [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) is not recommended due to its inefficiency.

When possible, it's recommended to use batch operations to write all the cells at once: [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) can be used for that (the same can be said for `getValue()` and `getValues()`).

`setValues(values)` requires a two-dimensional array of values, so the string `cell` should be transformed into a 2D array (where the outer array refers to the different rows, and the inner array elements refer to the columns). You could use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that:

```
function mySplit() {   
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2"); 
  var cell = doc.getRange("J21").getValue();
  var array = cell.split(",").map(el => [el]);
  doc.getRange(21, 10, array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Best Practices > Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)